# Run a couple of C# commands with a different user

Tags: c#, winforms, credentials, user-permissions

I have a winform C# application that needs to have access to different folders. To access each folder, I have to use different credentials.
I need to read the content the files inside the folders. The user who is running the application even doesn't have access to the check folders exists.
in other words

```
File.Exists
```

doesn't function due to lack o permission for the current user, which means to check the existence of folder I have to run File.Exists command by another user.

Is there any way to run a couple of C# commands with a user then a couple of other lines with other users?
Please note that I don't want to create a temp batch file then execute it as a bat script.

I was thinking of using

```
System.Diagnostics.Process
```

Is there any best practices or pattern for this problem?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/impersonating-and-reverting

Comment: Also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.runimpersonated?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0